# How can I tell what processes are involved in my TCP/IP stack?

Tags: networking, drm

For some reason, the machine I'm using is unable to access activate.adobe.com.

The Adobe Creative Cloud app, which is basically a package manager for Adobe software, is installed on my machine. The 'community' and 'assets' tabs are responding and populating properly, but the 'applications' tab that I would use to install applications does not load. It just spins endlessly.

Adobe tech support gave me a list of servers that need to be whitelisted. According to tech support, they SHOULD all respond to ping. Among them, activate.adobe.com fails a ping-test from me.

Ping returns the following:

```
PING activate.wip4.adobe.com (192.150.16.69): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
...etc
```

I suspect that the former user was mucking about, trying to beat the Adobe DRM scheme. activate.adobe.com was previously blocked in the hosts file, but I've removed the block. My hosts file is now clean and I've flushed the DNS cashe, and I've restarted. But activate.adobe.com is still not responding to ping, so I think the block might be coming from elsewhere.

Where else can I do do analyze the TCP/IP stack to see what might be the problem here?

Comment: Did you flush your DNS? `ipconfig /flushdns`. I recommend trying the same ping from another machine where someone would not have mucked with the hosts file. If possible then connect your phone to the WiFi at your company and try pinging it. I would be very shocked and suspicious if your administrator has configured this block at a local DNS level.

Comment: Or of course, you know, the service might be down/misconfigured. Take your pick.

Comment: Ping by itself doesn't prove much. Lots of Internet-accessible sites probably have ping blocked. What actual problem are you having?

Comment: You may want to check your firewall software/hardware to make sure its not blocking.

Comment: what do you mean "unable to access"

Comment: Thanks for all of these comments. I've edited and added to question above. I'll try checking another machine and connection once I have access to them.

Comment: So - it looks like the problem is actually my machine. So... any advice on how to figure out what might be in the middle of my TCP/IP stack blocking this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you have a problem, at least when it comes to networking.  I tried pinging those addresses and yes, you get a timeout.  However, that doesnt mean anything is wrong, Adobe is just blocking pings.  If you type both of the URLs into a browser, a page comes up.  Interesting, the pages arent coming up...

I think its a problem on Adobe's end, since the sites are down now.

FYI - Ping is not a good tool for testing connectivity.  At best, it will tell you something is up, at worst, it tells you nothing.

Comment: Sites are down now. Bah! You think tech support would have mentioned that. :( THank you.